# Dialogflow handles one webhook correctly but refuses another

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm currently using Glitch's(Glitch.com) node.js to connect Dialogflow to code and I'm running into a problem. As you can see below; I have two intents I'm trying to pass values to, characterHandler and openHandler.

Now the weird thing is that it **does** execute the web hook correctly if I trigger the intent on Dialogflow corresponding to "characterHandler", but it returns "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: no matching intent handler for: null" in the console and fails while triggering "openHandler" and I have no clue why.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require("request");
const { DialogflowApp } = require('actions-on-google');
const Map = require('es6-map');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());


let characters = ['The Pied Piper', 'Red Riding Hood', 'The Big Bad Wolf'];

// [START Action]
app.post('/', function (request, response) {
  const assistant = new DialogflowApp({request, response});
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

const CHARACTERS = 'story.characters';
const OPENINGTIMES = 'openingTimes';

  function characterHandler (assistant) {
    let responseText = "How about";

    responseText = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    assistant.tell(responseText);
  }

  function openHandler (assistant) {
    assistant.tell('This attraction is currently full');
  }

  const actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(CHARACTERS, characterHandler);
  actionMap.set(OPENINGTIMES, openHandler);

  assistant.handleRequest(actionMap);

});
// [END Action]

// Renders the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('');
  res.end();
});

if (module === require.main) {
  // [START server]
  // Start the server
  let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    let port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App listening on port %s', port);
  });
  // [END server]
}

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Check if you have accidentally enabled **Dialogflow V2 API** for your openHandler intent.

Comment: But I have Dialogflow V1 on, how am I possibly enabling it @sai.raj ?

Answer (score 0):

Your open handler function is mapped to 'openingTimes'. Make sure that exactly matches the intent name and make sure that the intent was actually saved correctly.